# Why does NSNumber round minus number while cast to unsigned integer?

Tags: objective-c, casting, unsigned, nsnumber

For example:

```
[@(-2.50001) unsignedIntegerValue] == -3
[@(-2.49999) unsignedIntegerValue] == -2
```

but:

```
[@(-2.50001) integerValue] == -2
[@(-2.49999) integerValue] == -2
```

Well, here is the code. I'm write a unit test of my code:

```
- (void)testUnsignedIntegerValue {
    XCTAssertEqual([@(-2.50001) unsignedIntegerValue], (NSUInteger)-3);
    XCTAssertEqual([@(-2.49999) unsignedIntegerValue], (NSUInteger)-2);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`NSNumber` docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber?language=objc):

> Because numeric types have different storage capabilities, attempting
>   to initialize with a value of one type and access the value of another
>   type may produce an erroneous result

Also, further down, [Table 4 – NSNumber from Floating Point Value Conversions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber?language=objc#2555743) shows specifically that querying the `unsignedIntegerValue` of an `NSNumber` created from a negative floating-point value produces "*invalid, erroneous result*".

What you're trying to do is inherently undefined and can't be made reliable.